# Most DHT node response fake 'values' at bep_0005 get_peers?

Tags: dht

When I use bep_0005 get_peers method to find an infohash like "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111", I can receive the response with "values' key, But when I use bep_0003 to send BitTorrent protocol handshake to each peer in "values", Peers always disconnect TCP connect, In fact, It seems Peers don't have ut_matadata.
Why node send me fake data?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes for this

- Old utorrent versions returned values stored for the nearest target key if they did not have an exact match. this was fixed a while ago but many people are still running old clients
- Various dubious implementations monitoring the DHT try to harvest data by responding to any and all `get peers` request with values and then recording connection attempts for whatever reasons
- Malicious entities use bittorrent clients as dDoS amplifiers by inducing them to spam targets with TCP connnections

But there are various measures a node can implement to sanitize that data.